# How to get data from $.post() request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, httprequest

I'm trying to send post `JQuery` request, but I can't get them out in server written using `Express`.

Right now, I was trying to send data in this way:

**Client side**

```
$.post('http://localhost:8080/numberOfAnsweres',{'val': 2})
```

**Server side**

```
app.post('/numberOfAnsweres',(req,res,next)=>{
    numberOfAnwers = req.??????
    console.log(numberOfAnwers)
})
```

I don't know which parameter of `req` should I use.
I'm also not sure if the sending method is good, is there any better way?

Comment: Did you check in the express docs? Generally the best place to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might get the values using express with:

```
app.post('/numberOfAnsweres',(req,res,next)=>{
    var name = req.body.name,
    var color = req.body.color;
    var value = req.body.val;
})
```

Comment: Should mention body parser also